# Webdriver.Chrome need extensions. ERROR "WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello guys I'm trying to pass trough Captcha with selenium, and for that, I need to launch Chrome with extensions. I'm trying to do it but nothing works, and keeps me showing this error (

```
Ocorreu uma exceção: TypeError
WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
  File "/Users/art/Documents/anticaptcha.py", line 22, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

) Can someone help me out?

Here's the code I tried to use

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile
import os
from pathlib import Path
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
import time


# definir opções de inicialização de navegador
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension('/Users/art/Documents/plugin.zip')

# definir opções de inicialização de navegador
browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options=options)

# navegue para a página de destino
browser.get('https://anti-captcha.com/demo/?page=recaptcha_v2_textarea')

# preencha o formulário
time.sleep(1)
browser.find_element(By.NAME,'login').send_keys('Test login')
browser.find_element(By.NAME,'pass').send_keys('Test password')

# aguardar pelo seletor "solved" para subir
webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.antigate_solver.solved'))

# pressione o botão enviar
browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'submitButton').click()
```

Thank's for your time!